# Cinemachine в Unity выдаёт NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я добавил в свой проект Scinemachine, накинул нужные компоненты на камеру и начал писать код что бы с помощью кнопки можно было изменить поле зрения. Когда я попытался изменить параметр Ortho Size через скрипт у меня всё пошло через одно место.
Вместо изменения значения он выдаёт вышеупомянутый NullReferenceException. Я уже проверял с помощью TryGetComponent, что вдруг он не туда накинулся, или ещё что, но нет, он возвращает мне значение MainCamera (Cinemachine.CinemachineVirtual camera), так что дело не в том что я неправильно накинул скрипт.

Вот код:

```
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine;

public class _Came : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CinemachineVirtualCamera CVC;

    [Range(1f, 10f)] 
    public float f = 5;
    

    private void Awake()
    {
        Camera.main.gameObject.TryGetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>(out var _camera);
        Debug.Log(_camera);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F)) 
        {
            CVC.m_Lens.OrthographicSize = f;
        }
    }
}
```

Может, это я слепой и не вижу проблемы у себя под носом, но я всё несколько раз проверил и даже создал новый проект, в котором протестировал этот же код с эти же расширением и у меня была эта же ошибка. В интернете я ничего подобного не нашёл, лишь пара вопросов на форумах, которые мне не помогли и больше ничего.

Upd: я и правда слепой и случайно удалил присваивание полю CVC значения с Camera.main.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out var _camera), но я удалил это недавно и до этого скрипт всё так же сыпал ошибками. Спасибо комментатору.

Comment: Поле CVC пустое, ты ему ничего не присваиваешь, в трайгеткомпонент ты передаешь новую только что созданную переменную